# How to add Caching Header meta to a CSS, JS and images using joomla?

Tags: php, css, joomla, http-headers, cache-control

I'm working to make the joomla faster,how ever it work in PHP.
I would like to apply the caching on the CSS,JS and images.

I read this topic [Leverage browser cahing](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching#LeverageBrowserCaching) and this is what i need, **But i don't know how to apply it.**

Those are the meta that I need to add.
Expires, Cache-Control: max-age, Last-Modified and ETag.
[image]

Comment: Joomla already has a caching option in the Global Configuration

Comment: @lodder I applied the cache in the Global Configuration. but the headers meta still not added to CSS , Js or Images.